# How can I show that this curve is a great circle on the unit sphere?

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, geodesic

I have the following curve specified in spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$*:

$$K^2 \tan^2(\phi-\phi_0) = \tan^2 \theta - K^2 \sec^2 \theta, \quad r=1,$$

where $K$ and $\phi_0$ are constants.

I want to try and show that this specifies a great circle on the unit sphere. I'm not sure how to intuitively see this is the case.

I have tried to convert to Cartesian coordinates to arrive at an equation of the form $f(x,y,z)=0$, but after doing this I still do not see how to arrive at the conclusion that this is a great circle.

<sub>*I am using the convention that $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ is the inclination and $\phi \in [0,2π)$ is the azimuth, that is, $x=r \sin \theta \cos \phi$, $y=r \sin \theta \sin \phi$, $z=r \cos \theta$.</sub>

Comment: "Spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$" is unfortunately ambiguous due to multiple conventions; can you please say which angle ($\theta$, $\phi$) connotes what (longitude, latitude, colatitude)? The work you've done converting to Cartesian might be helpful to include as well if it's not too difficult.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang right. I am using the convention that $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ is the inclination and $\phi \in [0, 2 \pi) $ is the azimuth, that is $x=r \sin \theta \cos \phi$, $y = r \sin \theta \sin \phi$, $z = r \cos \theta$. I can update my post with my conversion to Cartesian later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A point on the unit sphere has Cartesian coordinates

$P = (\sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \theta) $

Starting with the given equation

$K^2 \tan^2(\phi - \phi_0) = \tan^2(\theta) - K^2 \sec^2(\theta) $

Using the identity $\sec^2(\theta) = 1 + \tan^2(\theta) $ the above equation becomes

$K^2 \tan^2(\phi - \phi_0) = (1 - K^2) \tan^2(\theta) - K^2 $

Multiply through by $\cos^2(\phi - \phi_0) \cos^2 \theta $, you get

$ K^2 \sin^2(\phi - \phi_0) \cos^2 \theta = (1 - K^2) \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 (\phi - \phi_0) - K^2 \cos^2(\phi - \phi_0) \cos^2 \theta $

This re-arranges into

$ K^2 \cos^2 \theta ( \sin^2(\phi - \phi_0) + \cos^2(\phi - \phi_0) ) = (1 - K^2) \sin^2 \theta \cos^2(\phi - \phi_0) $

which reduces to

$ K^2 \cos^2 \theta = (1 - K^2) \sin^2 \theta \cos^2(\phi - \phi_0) $

The solution of the above equation is

$ K \cos \theta = \pm \sqrt{1 - K^2} \sin \theta \cos(\phi - \phi_0) $

Here, we have to assume that $| K | \le 1 $

Expanding the right hand side

$ K \cos \theta = \pm \sqrt{1 - K^2} \sin \theta \left( \cos \phi \cos \phi_0 + \sin \phi \sin \phi_0 \right) $

Now recall the expression for a point $P$ on the unit sphere, then the above equation says

$ [ \pm \sqrt{1 - K^2} \cos \phi_0 , \pm \sqrt{1 - K^2} \sin \phi_0 , - K ] \cdot P = 0 $

which is of the form

$ N \cdot P = 0 $

and this is an equation of a plane passing through the origin.  Since $P$ is on the unit sphere, then the intersection of the plane and the sphere is a great circle.  Taking the plus and minus cases, this implies that the original equation corresponds to two possible great circles.